# Function pointer to class member function

Tags: c++

I want to make function which has function pointer as a parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{

public:
    test(){};

    double tt(double input){
        return input;
    };

};

double fptr_test(double (*fptr)(double), double input){
    return fptr(input);
}


int main(){

    test t;
    cout << t.tt(3) << endl;
    cout << fptr_test(t.tt, 3) << endl;  // This line doesn't work
    cout << fptr_test(&test::tt, 3) << endl;  // This line can't compile

    return 1;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
How could I pass class member function as a parameter?

Can I call the member function without instantiation?

Comment: Short answer: "pointer to function" and "pointer to member function" both exist, but they're not the same as each other, and you can't substitute one for the other either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function pointer and a member function pointer have incompatible types. For example, the type of `&test::tt` is

```
double (test::*)(double)
```

rather than

```
double (*)(double)
```

The reason for this difference is that a [non-`static`] member function has a hidden parameter: the pointer to the object the member function is applied, too, i.e., `this`. The way to a normal function pointer out of a member function is to delegate via a function which supplies the `this` pointer and, thus, takes an extra argument.

In C++ it is much more useful to *not* take function pointers as arguments to functions which can be customized by a function but rather to take a *function object*. This approach comes in two flavors:

1. The fast approach is to make the function object type a template argument and to just pass whatever function object you got directly. For example, you `fptr_test()` would look like this:

   ```
   template <typename Fun>
   double fptr_test(Fun fun, double input) {
       return fun(input);
   }
   ```

   The implicit *concept* used is a function callable with a `double` argument which yields are result convertible to `double`.
2. Especially when the functions being called need to be compiled separately, using a template for each kind of function object isn't viable. In that case it is much more reasonable to use a type-erased representation, i.e., `std::function<...>`, e.g.:

   ```
   double fptr_test(std::function<double(double)> fun, double input) {
       return fun(input);
   }
   ```

In both cases the function object takes just one argument while your member function takes two: the object to call the function on and the `double` argument. You'd `std::bind(...)` the first argument to an object and pass the resulting object to `fptr_test()`:

```
  test object;
  std::cout << fptr_test(std:bind(&test::tt, &object, std::placeholders::_1), 3) << '\n';
  std::cout << fptr_test([&](double input){ return object.tt(input); }, 3) << '\n';
```

The code uses two separate approaches to bind the object: the first uses `std::bind()` while the second uses a lambda function. Both of these calls should work with both of the implementation of `fptr_test()` provided.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a pointer to a member-function, you need to use a member-function-pointer, not a pointer for generic free functions and an object to invoke it on.

Neither is optional.

```
double fptr_test(test& t, double (test::*fptr)(double), double input){
    return t.*fptr(input);
}

// call like this:
fptr_test(&test::tt, 3); // Your second try
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class test{

public:
    test(){};

    double tt(double input){
        return input;
    };

};

double fptr_test( std::function<double(double)> func, double input){
    return func(input);
}


int main(){
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    test t;
    cout << t.tt(3) << endl;
    cout << fptr_test( std::bind( &test::tt, t, _1 ), 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Btw - when your program finishes correctly you suppose to return 0 from `main()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code after modification.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{

public:
    test(){};

    double tt(double input){
        return input;
    };

};

double fptr_test(test* t, double (test::*fptr)(double), double input){
    return (t->*fptr)(input);
}

int main(){

    test t;
    cout << t.tt(3) << endl;
    cout << fptr_test(&t, &test::tt, 3) << endl;

    return 1;
}
```